# how to know string contains xml data or not using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

**how to know string contains XML data or not using java script ?**

i am using the following code.

```
if(str.substr(1,5) == '<?xml')
{
alert("xml data");
}else{
alert('not an xml data');
}
```

*The problem is some times my XML (str) data does not contains ?xml .............
tag so this code is not working for me*

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose using two possible options here:

1. This one is to use jquery 1.9.1. You can simply pass your string to it, and it will try to parse it. If done - will return length that is greater than 0. Otherwise - will return 0 or throw exception if string is not well formed XML.
   Working sample is here: http://jsfiddle.net/fqCNL/
2. This one is to use javascript DOM Parser. 
   The logic is pretty similar. You should try to parse string with parser. If it's firsChild is not defined and firstChildElement local name is 'parsererror' - then it's not xml or not valid xml. Also exception should be handled if it fails - that also will mean that this is simple string, not a valid xml.
   Working sample is here: http://jsfiddle.net/MwKcq/
   Note, that for cross-browser work of this method (primarily for IE) - you'll have to check for `if (window.DOMParser)` and if it does not exist - use another part for parsing:
   `xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
   xmlDoc.async=false;
   xmlDoc.loadXML(text);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function xmpresent(xml){
 try {
 var Resultss = $.xml2json(data.message);
 return true;
 }
 catch (e) { 
 return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Note : Download jquery.xml2json.js from http://www.bvbcode.com/code/sdakv8fj-895625-down

Answer (score -1):

You can use indexOf()

```
if(str.indexOf('<?xml') != -1){
}else{}
```

Comment: but my XML data is like  this   <note>
    <to> Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

Comment: And what is the issue you see with my approach? Did you try this already?

Comment: yes i tried .my XML data is coming from server ,some times it is not well formed XML that means it does not contain<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> tag in that case it not working for me ,please provide any other solution.

Comment: Hmm how exactly are you getting this data? An Ajax call or is it directly on the page also do you see any js errors on your developer tools?